# Error in converting String to Date in Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, unhandled-exception, default-constructor, parseexception

```
DateFormat d1;
d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");

public String duedate = "20-April.2019";
Date du =  d1.parse(duedate);
```

The Error I keep getting is:

> Default constructor cannot handle exception type ParseException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit 
>    constructor

Comment: This mysterious JavaDoc...

Comment: `dd-MMMM-yyyy` and `20-April.2019`: `-` vs `.`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first two in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalDate`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I can get various other error messages depending on how and where I paste your code into my Eclipse, but not the one you are quoting. Could you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Comment: @DrMido It’s better to add tags that describe *the problem or error being asked about* than tags that generally describe *the code* or its desired result.

Comment: BTW I don’t think any of the three answers posted here so far will remedy the error message you quote. Some of the answers to the linked original question are wrong too, but I think that at least the high-voted ones are OK.

Comment: [Search for `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+localdate+java+datetimeformatter+parse&t=iphone&ia=web) classes.

Answer (score 0):

It should have only three 'M'.

```
d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

And the date should not have a dot.

```
String duedate = "20-April-2019";
Date du =  d1.parse(duedate);
```

Comment: For most languages 4 'M' would be correct since the string contains the full month name. 3 'M' is for month abbreviation like `Apr`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the dateFormat and the duedate must correspond, so if your dateFormat uses dashes, the duedate can't use dots

```
String duedate = "20-April-2019";
```

Secondly you have to consider the ParseException error, so you have to surround the declaration of Date with a try/catch like this:

```
try{
    Date du =  d1.parse(duedate);
} catch(ParseException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find information how to parse date string using SimpleDateFormat here: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

The error appears, because your date format string is not matched by the date string you are trying to parse.